# Require_once not working after Web-hook event some data

Tags: php, include, webhooks, require-once

We are using acuity web-hook for send appointment data to our software.The data send to below php file.

workflow.php

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/bitrix/header.php');
$cmd = 'echo "hii3" > debug.log';
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd)."</pre>";
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php";
```

If I use require_once then trigger did not goes to header.php, but when I use include then the trigger goes to header.php.

Comment: _If I use require_once then trigger did not goes to header.php, but when I use include then the trigger goes to header.php._ This is because _require_   a not exisiting file will lead to a fatal error, where include does not

Comment: Good god man, I saw at least 2 possible exploits with this script. Also the file MAY not be where you think it is. require will throw a fatal.

Comment: But we use include then header.php executing and when we use require_once then header.php not executing.I dont know why??

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var_dump(file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/bitrix/header.php'));
```

to verify that the file actually exists. If not the require_once() will throw an error.
Aside from that the behavior of include() and require() is the same.